# geometry - two secants

Tags: circles, ratio, secant

Given a circle whose centre is "o" with 2 secants; "abc" and "aef" (both of them start in point a, which is out of the circle).

The radius is called $r$.
Also, the value if $AB \cdot AC$ is known, ab*ac= M.

find the length of the line that connects the centre and point "a" (line "ao") by using only "M" and "r".

If it helps, the answer is $\sqrt{m+r^2}$. I need the solution method.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAnXK.png)

p.s. I hope I was clear enough, I don't have a rich English vocabulary regarding to math.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AP$ be a tangent of the circle, where $P$ is a touching point.

Thus, $$AP\perp OP$$ and  $$AP^2=AB\cdot AC=m,$$ which gives $$AP=\sqrt{m}$$ and
$$AO=\sqrt{OP^2+AP^2}=\sqrt{r^2+m}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually got it eventually by myself...

Comment: @Yoel Marko You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. after I published it, it seemed a lot simpler.

I just draw a tnagent from "A" and connected a radius to it.
Then, the angle between them is 90 deg' and we can represent AO as squrt of (R^2 + the tangent).

Now represent the tangent by using the statement that a tangent in the power of two is equal to the outside of a secant times all the secant. Which we already know as "M".

Now replace and that's it!